# Word for "modern technological (industry?)"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that means something similar to industry, but not exactly (and I have already used industry in my sentenc)e:

"Silicon is an incredibly important material in the electronics industry, being used for making for diodes and transistors which form the basis of modern technological __________"

Comment: What's wrong with *"...used for making diodes and transistors, which form the basis of modern technologies."*?

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/industry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Silicon is an incredibly important material in the electronics industry, being used for making for diodes and transistors which form the basis of modern technological advances"

Or

"Silicon is an incredibly important material in the electronics industry, being used for making for diodes and transistors which form the basis of contemporary technological progress/ advances"

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't perfectly fit your question, but it does perfectly fit your example:

> Silicon is an incredibly important material in the electronics industry, being used for making for diodes and transistors which form the basis of modern technological **era**.